# Impossible to send email using Postfix behind Squid proxy server

Tags: postfix, configuration, proxy

I've just installed this pre-built virtual machine which is built on Ubuntu Server 10.04 and works greatly but I can't send email from command line.
I'm 100% sure it's a configuration problem of the postfix server but I don't know where to put hands.
I have total ssh access and also webmin...

Any hints?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What kind of proxy server? Does it have SMTP support? Can you change its configuration, or at least ask its admin to make changes for you?

Comment: I can change the configuration without problems...
We have 2 proxy server so I can use the "easiest" to tweak.
One is squid (debian) and the other is an astaro security gateway which also act as proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Squid is a HTTP/HTTPS proxy, it doesn't have anything to do with SMTP or other mail protocols. Do the people running the network have a mail relay or smarthost you can use to relay the mail out through? Then all you'll have to do is add a line like `relayhost = relay.company.com` to Postfix's main.cf which will tell  Postfix to relay mail through that host. However, this will be a mail relay, not a proxy.